Regarding technical/engineering sciences perspective of vulnerability (around 1960s) in disaster risk reduction (DRR) context
Does anybody know something about, or someone who has resources on, the engineering science perspective of the concept of vulnerability in natural disaster risk reduction and management? I found in my research how the technical/engineering sciences purely focused on damages in structural systems (e.g. built structures) due to hazards (anything hazard-related applies), but I was unable to find any more research that actually focused as such, which is made much harder in part due to this focus being in the 1960s, I think, before Western social sciences entered with their own perspective. Any kind of help or tips or studies would be appreciated, thank you!
I intend to learn more and receive researches regarding this particular perspective in vulnerability, possibly develop a coherent, empirical view on the subject.

Do you mean FMEAs? been around in various forms since 1948. Otherwise it might be worth explaining what you are getting at.

I think you are leading me towards the right direction. Also, by disaster, I mean natural disasters, so it would be helpful to learn more about FMEAs if they have been applied in the context of natural hazards such as hurricanes, or fires, or earthquakes, but particularly in (tropical) cyclones.

I don't know how civil engineers handle this.
